# Is this use case extension point named correctly?

Tags: uml, use-case

Look at this use case scenario

[image]

The use case that creates justifications will just be included **if** the actor wants that. So, is `the actor requests that` considered a valid extension point?

Answer (score 1):

In general, the definition of the semantics of use cases is quite weak and informal in UML. Many aspects are left open or given to users interpretation impicitly or even explicitly. And as you as ask for naming of extension points, there is no naming convention in UML for the user of it. Thus there is no UML defined notion of correctness of names. But, there are many approaches that are commonly used, so you named your use case already with a verb fallowed by a noun, what is a very common scheme for use case names.

For extension points, there you can provide an extension specification that is anchored to the extends relation. An extension specification contains the extension point it is related to and a condition that specifies when the extension point is used. The naming of the extension point is also not specified but there are two common schemes: first it is named in accordance to an action that an actor can trigger, e.g., "on selection of item x". Second, named in accordance to what the extension does, e.g., "Provide information". The second case is somehow redundant to what is given in the extending use case, but allows better documentation and linking to requiremetns. The name you have given is too generic, as you  neither give a specification of what need to happen to trigger the use case nor what happens if it is triggered.